# I am implementing GAN to generate samples for ID-VG curve. But the Fake data generated is not same as real generated samples

Tags: python

In this example, we generate 1000 real samples using the generate_real_samples function. We then define the generator and discriminator networks using the define_generator and define_discriminator functions, respectively, and connect them to create the GAN model using the define_gan function.

We then call the train function to train the generator and discriminator on the real dataset, which will update the weights of the GAN model. Finally, we call the summarize_performance function to evaluate the performance of the generator and discriminator on a set of real and fake samples and generate a plot of the generated samples.

```
# train a generative adversarial network on a one-dimensional function

from numpy import hstack
import numpy as np
from numpy import zeros
from numpy import ones
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy.random import randn
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import Input
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

LENGTH_INPUT=50 # gate length 
un=900
cox=5e-3
import numpy as np

# generate n real samples with class labels

def generate_real_samples(n):
L = np.arange(0.012,300,0.08)
W = np.arange(0.02,300,0.8)
vt=0.3
\# freqs = np.linspace(1,2,1000)
X2 = np.linspace(0.4,0.7,LENGTH_INPUT)
X1 = \[\]
for x in range(n):
noise = np.random.normal(size=len(X2))
\# id=un*cox*(W/L)*(i-vt)\*\*2
X1.append(np.log(un*cox\*( np.random.choice(W)/ np.random.choice(L))*(X2-vt)\*\*2)+0.1*noise)
X1 = np.array(X1).reshape(n, LENGTH_INPUT)
\# generate class labels
y = ones((n, 1))
return X1, y
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Flatten
from keras.layers import ELU, PReLU, LeakyReLU
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# Set the length input to 50

LENGTH_INPUT = 50

# Set the values for un and cox

un = 900
cox = 5e-3

# Define the generator model

def define_generator(latent_dim):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=latent_dim))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dense(LENGTH_INPUT, activation='tanh'))
return model

# Define the discriminator model

def define_discriminator(input_shape):
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=\['accuracy'\])
return model

# Define the GAN model

def define_gan(generator, discriminator):
discriminator.trainable = False
model = Sequential()
model.add(generator)
model.add(discriminator)
opt = Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
return model

# Generate n real samples with class labels

def generate_real_samples(n):
L = np.arange(0.012, 300, 0.08)
W = np.arange(0.02, 300, 0.8)
vt = 0.3
X2 = np.linspace(0.4, 0.7, LENGTH_INPUT)
X1 = \[\]
for x in range(n):
noise = np.random.normal(size=LENGTH_INPUT)
X1.append(np.log(un \* cox \* (np.random.choice(W) / np.random.choice(L)) \* (X2 - vt) \*\* 2) + 0 \* noise)
X1 = np.array(X1).reshape(n, LENGTH_INPUT)
y = np.ones((n, 1))
return X1, y

# Generate latent points

def generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n):
x_input = np.random.randn(latent_dim \* n)
x_input = x_input.reshape(n, latent_dim)
return x_input

# Use the generator to generate n fake samples with class labels

def generate_fake_samples(generator, latent_dim, n):
x_input = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n)
X = generator.predict(x_input)
y = np.zeros((n, 1))
return X, y

# Train the generator and discriminator models

def train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, latent_dim, n_epochs, n_batch):
half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)
n_eval=50
for i in range(n_epochs):
# Train discriminator on real samples
X_real, y_real = generate_real_samples(half_batch)
d_loss_real, \_ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_real, y_real)

        # Train discriminator on fake samples
        X_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, half_batch)
        d_loss_fake, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_fake, y_fake)
    
        # Train generator via the GAN model
        x_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_batch)
        y_gan = np.ones((n_batch, 1))
        g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(x_gan, y_gan)
    
        # Print progress
        print('Epoch %d/%d, Discriminator Loss: [Real: %.3f, Fake: %.3f], Generator Loss: %.3f' % (i+1, n_epochs, d_loss_real, d_loss_fake, g_loss))
        if (i+1) % n_eval == 0:
            plt.title('Number of epochs = %i'%(i+1))
            pred_data = generate_fake_samples(generator,latent_dim,latent_dim)[0]
            real_data  = generate_real_samples(latent_dim)[0]
            plt.plot(pred_data[0],'.',label='Random Fake Sample',color='firebrick')
            plt.plot(real_data[0],'.',label = 'Random Real Sample',color='navy')
            plt.legend(fontsize=10)
            plt.show()

# Define the size of the latent space

latent_dim = 100

# Create the generator, discriminator, and GAN models

generator = define_generator(latent_dim)
discriminator = define_discriminator((LENGTH_INPUT,))
gan_model = define_gan(generator, discriminator)

# Train the GAN model

n_epochs = 60000
n_batch = 128
train(generator, discriminator, gan_model, latent_dim, n_epochs, n_batch)

\[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMLoI.png)\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSYMv.png) as we can see the fake data cannot samples real data if its below than -1 point.
```